# AWS console search in array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for a string that I can paste into AWS search(searching volumes for example) in browser so I can look for volume names/id's either like "foo" or like "bar", so in essence "if in array" type of search.

I tried multiple approaches and fail on every one. Only thing that I can do is paste my string, hit enter, paste another one, hit enter, its feasible for 2 strings but not for 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: \bFOO|\bBAR**

---

If you click the "?" button in the search field (at least in EC2) you get a "search help" view describing advanced usages of the search bar:
[image]

This help page shows that you can use regular expressions. This one should work for your use case:  [\bFOO|\bBAR](https://www.regextester.com/93690)

---

Help window screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Sure but as far as i can see neither has array search as an option, does it mean its not possible? Regex would be too much, tried that one as well

Comment: Will try what you bolded at the top

Comment: Yep, that's regexp but a pretty simple one. It seems to work well for me.

Comment: ye probably tried it with bad regex, after trying bunch of stuff my brain was a bit fried probably